# Elixir ExUnit test with custom dependency environnement

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

I have a project A, which depends on a dependency B created by me also...

when I want to launch test on A with a simple `mix test`, it's getting the dependecy B, compiling it and starting it in `:prod` environnement...

Which mean A is in `:test` environnement and B is in `:prod` env.

I would like for the tests to launch the dependency in `:dev` environnement (or anything else but `:prod`), is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Although it looks an overkill here, one might introduce [their own compiler](http://elixir-lang.org/blog/2012/04/24/a-peek-inside-elixir-s-parallel-compiler/) and delegate compilation of `B` project in the requested environment to it. That way the project `B` in local would always have been compiled in the same environment as `A` currently is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your `MIX_ENV` is `prod` and `mix test` doesn't change it to `test`.
Try explicitly:

```
MIX_ENV=test mix test

and for dev

MIX_ENV=dev mix test
```

Comment: Actually, the issue is not here, I do not have MIX_ENV env variable set. However you pointed me out to my mistakes that Mix.env was used a compile time not running time.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't accept the answer as it is... edit it so you point the difference between compile time Mix.env (in :prod) and running time Mix.env, and I will :-)

Comment: “I do not have MIX_ENV env variable set”—you always do. If you have not set it explicitly, `mix` has done it for you.

Comment: @mudasobwa: what I meant is I didn't ```export MIX_ENV=prod```... of course that mix does it for you, but I don't overcharge it...